# Add and Center image inside CALayer

Tags: swift, uiimage, calayer

I want to center the image inside a CALayer. Even the image size must be modified accordingly and color of image should also be tinted. The problem is Im not able to set the image size and even add color.

```
    //premium gradient
    let premiumViewLayer=CALayer()
    premiumViewLayer.bounds=CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:(getGradientWidth()), height:(LKView.bounds.height))
    premiumViewLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    let premiumimageViewLayer=CALayer()
    premiumimageViewLayer.frame = SSView.frame
    premiumimageViewLayer.contents=UIImage(named: "premium")?.cgImage
    premiumimageViewLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter

    premiumViewLayer.addSublayer(premiumimageViewLayer)
```

I want to achieve something like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try This one its working  :::**

```
  let premiumViewLayer=CALayer()
    premiumViewLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imgView.frame.size)//CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:375, height:333.5)
    premiumViewLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    premiumViewLayer.contents=UIImage(named: "premium")?.cgImage
    premiumViewLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
    view(on which on want to add this layer).layer.addSublayer(premiumViewLayer)
```

Comment: the image of lock is too big compare to the layer

Comment: can you tell me the size of an image ...
Or take image size a/c to your requirement like 2x or 3x

Comment: 2x is the size of image.Image is too big.